# Slow connection to a shared .mdb file over a LAN on some machines only

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, microsoft-access

A single client program on each of about 10 computers are sharing a .mdb file on a windows 7 machine.
The network is cabled and has a switch.
For no obvious reason the connection on 2 of these computers as evidenced by the user experience with the client program has become very slow.
The problem arose on the 2 computers simultaneously. 
The performance on all other computers is unaffected.
On the problem computers it is possible to navigate with windows explorer to the folder that stores the database without any undue delay.
The only antivirus in operation appears to be windows defender.
Different ports on the switch have been used without any improvement.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions as to possible causes

EDIT after cause of problem found.

Sorry for wasting peoples' time. The CPU and memory on the folder holding the file being shared was being gobbled up and another program that had gone mental and was creating lots of processes.
Killing these off solved the problem

Comment: Not entirely convinced this is the *right* way to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you write your fix as an answer, and accept your own answer? Makes the place look tidier